# Can't Insert Product List Widget

Tags: magento2, widget

I have a Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1.

When I try to insert the "catalog product list" widget on a CMS page with the below code:

```
<p>{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="0" products_count="1" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`sku`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:``^]^]"}}</p>
```

It gives me this error:

> "Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Magento \ CatalogWidget
> \ Block \ Product \ ProductsList"

I'm going crazy I don't understand the reason for the mistake.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested that feature on your site. Adding **Catalog New Product List** works fine, but **Catalog Product List** has the error.

I Can see that you have installed at least 3 3rd-party modules: Mageplaza SMTP, Product Inquiry, and Amage Cms (Import/Export CMS). So, let's try to disable all of these modules to check if **Catalog Product List** Wiget works or not.

Run the following commands to disable 3 3rd-party modules:

```
bin/magento module:disable Mageplaza_Smtp Sparsh_ProductInquiry Amage_Cms
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Then go to the frontend to test the result.

Case 1: If after disabling 3 modules above the issue still persists, enable these modules again and continue debugging.

Run the following commands to enable 3 3rd-party modules:

```
bin/magento module:disable Mageplaza_Smtp Sparsh_ProductInquiry Amage_Cms
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Case 2: If after disabling 3 modules above the issue is resolved, enable each module one by one to test.

2.1: Run the following commands to enable Mageplaza_Smtp module:

```
bin/magento module:enable Mageplaza_Smtp
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Then test

2.2: If after enabling Mageplaza_Smtp module the issue is still resolved, that means Mageplaza_Smtp module does not cause the error. Run the following commands to enable Sparsh_ProductInquiry modules:

```
bin/magento module:enable Sparsh_ProductInquiry
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Then test

2.3: If after enabling Sparsh_ProductInquiry module the issue is still resolved, that means Sparsh_ProductInquiry module does not cause the error. Looks like Amage_Cms module causes the error, but still need to check for sure. Run the following commands to enable Amage_Cms modules:

```
bin/magento module:enable Amage_Cms
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Then test, if after enabling Amage_Cms module the issue persists. Run the following commands to disable that module:

```
bin/magento module:disable Amage_Cms
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: doesnt work this widget   {{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="0" products_count="1" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`sku`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:``^]^]"}}

Comment: Could you confirm you tried my code but the issue still persists?

Comment: i tried but persist =(

Comment: do you have any advice???

Comment: do you install any 3rd-party modules (extensions) or did you create any custom modules?

Comment: no 3rd-party modules or custom modules

Comment: i'm sorry but doesn't work your solution

Comment: "Sorry, an error occurred while generating this content."

Comment: looks like this error has been fixed, isn't it? did you tried add the widget to CMS page again?

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work....

Comment: Could you send me the admin user credentials here https://onetimesecret.com/? I'll try.

Comment: https://onetimesecret.com/secret/f0swb5yqfw2vukh9zj6zn54k59nxz06

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check.

Comment: what is the best procedure to disable module?

Comment: I've updated the answer to tell you how to disable modules and instructions for debugging.

Comment: i've disable Sparsh_ProductInquiry and now widget product list works..thanks

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you override the widget / is it custom ?
This error is given when the paths aren't right.
Check if all the paths are correct

Comment: hi i am using the magento default widget. What do you mean by "paths aren't right". Can you give me an example?

You can see the error here https://corsomagento2.com/test

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Is there a solution? Error disapears after deaktivating Sparsh ProductInquiry. I need the Plugin, so is there a solution?